# How to retrieve data from Node JS sever to Flutter using DIO?

Tags: node.js, flutter, jwt, backend, dio

I'm implementing my backend using NodeJs and have tested it on Postman. The value is stored on headers so I'm using this method:

```
getUser(token) async {
    dio.options.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer $token';
    return await dio.get('https://votewithblocks-backend.herokuapp.com/getUser');
}
```

Where I'm passing jwt token and then decoding the user info.
But this doesn't seem to work and I do not know why.

Also I'm not understanding how to return user value when ever the screen changes. I've tried `InitState` but I'm not getting any output

```
AuthService().getUser(token).then((value) {
         setState(() {
          name = value.data['name'];
          voterID = value.data['voterID'];
});
```

This is the method that i want to call in initstate where I need to return user name and his/her voterID.

But there seems to something that I'm doing wrong so that I'm not getting the output.

PS: I'm new to working with backend and flutter.
[image]

This is the Output I'm getting from Postman while calling getUser() method

Comment: Can you provide more info on what is returned by getUser()

Comment: getUser() method takes a JWT Token and decodes the JWT Token and returns VoterID and Name

Comment: This is the function definition 
getUser: function (req, res) {
        if(req.headers.authorization && req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[0] === "Bearer") {
            var token = req.headers.authorization.split(" ")[1];
            const decoded = jwt.decode(token, config.secret);
            const {voterID, name} = decoded;
            return res.json({success: true, msg: "Successful logged in.", user: name, voterID: voterID});
        }
        else{
            return res.status(400).send({success: false, msg: "No token provided."});
        }
    }

Comment: Update the question with details of the working Postman request. Try with regular `package:http` instead of Dio. What does this print? `print((await http.get(Uri.parse('https://votewithblocks-backend.herokuapp.com/getUser'), headers: {'authorization': 'Bearer xxxx'})).body);`

Comment: @RichardHeap just stated same thing I'm trying to say. I ont see any error in your code.Try to log the response you get from the api. Try this code and check what it prints?
`getUser(token) async {
    dio.options.headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer $token';
    Respnse response = await dio.get('https://votewithblocks-backend.herokuapp.com/getUser');
print(response.data);
return response;
}`

Comment: I/flutter ( 6520): Http status error [400]
E/flutter ( 6520): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'data' was called on null.
E/flutter ( 6520): Receiver: null
E/flutter ( 6520): Tried calling: data
E/flutter ( 6520): #0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:68:5)
E/flutter ( 6520): #1      _LoginScreenState.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>
package:login_app_node/login_screen.dart:117
E/flutter ( 6520): #2      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1436:47)

Comment: This is the error im getting

Comment: @RichardHeap I did try out your method aswell and I recieved this
I/flutter ( 6520): <pre>Internal Server Error</pre>
I/flutter ( 6520): </body>
I/flutter ( 6520): </html>
E/flutter ( 6520): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'data' was called on null.
E/flutter ( 6520): Receiver: null
E/flutter ( 6520): Tried calling: data

Comment: On postman the getUser methods returns 
{
    "success": true,
    "msg": "Successful logged in.",
    "user": "Vdx",
    "voterID": "1122112211"
}

Comment: The word `data` does not appear in *my* snippet (but does appear in the other commenters snippet). Try mine again. Copy it carefully (and replace xxx with the correct token). Also, unless you post a screenshot of your working Postman request, it's going to take a long time to solve this.

Comment: Error: NoSuchMethodError: 'data'
method not found
Receiver: null
Arguments: []

These are the Errors That I've got